# Thinklight won't work since Update to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, 19.04

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad X200s with Lubuntu.
Yesterday I updated my system to Version 19.04, but the ThinkLight won't work any more using the short cut.

Trying to set it manually by changing to

```
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinklight
```

and setting `echo 255 | sudo tee brightness` won't change anything. (But works).

Do I have to set anything new? 
Thank you

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/7n8eyu/thinkpad_led_control_under_gnulinux/

Comment: No changes - I assume the Update did something

Comment: You can install an older kernel version that had support: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165